# POST Method keeps on getting "404 Not found" error

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am using AJAX through Jquery to send data from one jsp file to another. But the ajax calling function keeps getting an error 404 not found.

My code gets executed till 'alert("JS entered");' but after that it throws the request failed alert.

```
function Search()
            {
                alert("JS entered");
                var a = document.getElementById("selement").value;
                console.log(a);
                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "Search.jsp",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        branch_code: a

                    }
                });

                request.done(function (msg) {

                });

                request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
                    console.log("error here")
                });
            }
```

what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Is your Search.jsp file at the same level as the file that calls it?

Comment: pls check the location of Search.jsp

Comment: Give a screenshot of your project structure

Comment: looks like an incorrect file path [for the search file] I'd also check if selement is correctly spelled and is in fact an id in the [unprovided] HTML and not accidentally in as a class. Does the console log the value ok?